# Ionic 3 confirm pop-up remove item from list

Tags: popup, ionic3, alert

I have an app where a user is able to delete another user. When the user clicks the delete button, a pop-up window appears asking the user if they are sure they want to take this action. When the user clicks confirm, I'd like the user to be deleted. 
I achieved this initially before by putting a remove method on the button, like this:

```
<button ion-button (click)="remove(i);">Delete</button>
```

And in my .ts I had this code:

```
this.items = [
              {user: 'UserA'},
              {user: 'UserB'}
          ];

  remove(no) {
    (this.items).splice(no, 1);
  }
```

My problem is that now, when the user clicks the button, the method top open the popup is called:

```
<button ion-button (click)="showConfirmAlert();">Delete</button>
```

And I'm not sure now how to remove the item from the list.

```
showConfirmAlert() {
        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'Confirm delete user',
            message: 'Are you sure you want to permanently delete this user?',
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: 'No',
                    handler: () => {
                        console.log('Cancel clicked');
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: 'Yes',
                    handler: () => {

                    }
                }
            ]
        })
      }
```

Do I need to write a separate remove function, inside the showConfirmAlert method? How do I go about doing this? Sorry, very new here, any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your html file:

```
<button ion-button (click)="showConfirmAlert(i);">Delete</button>
```

In your ts file:

```
showConfirmAlert(i) {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Confirm delete user',
        message: 'Are you sure you want to permanently delete this user?',
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'No',
                handler: () => {
                    console.log('Cancel clicked');
                }
            },
            {
                text: 'Yes',
                handler: () => {
                   this.items.splice(i,1);
                }
            }
        ]
    })
  }
```